# Update app on the App Store

Tags: ios, upgrade

Here is my scenario:

My app has version X in the app store, then I want to upload version X+1 to the store.

There has been a major change between version X and version X+1.
Both apps were using backgroundFetch to do some of the work

Assuming version X was opened, and version X+1 was never opened after downloading, will i still be receiving backgroundFetch events ?

Comment: I think no. Because background fetches start when the app is opened. So if you don't open app ever your app won't start the background fetch. Think about permissions, if the user don't open the app, app won't have permission.

Comment: but it has been previously opened on a previous version

Comment: @grhnkdlk I don't think permission is an issue here, I have some apps using access to photo library, push notifications or geolocation, user isn't asked again to authorize those features when the app is updated.

Comment: @JeromeDiaz but Lena said version X was ever opened so version X+1 won't have permission too

Comment: @grhnkdlk ever opened = opened at least once

Comment: @LenaBru I thought that never opened :/ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From Apple:
>
> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the device before the app can be launched automatically into the background by the system.

It means the app `need` to receive backgroundFetch events for `X+1`.

Comment: so the app WILL receive those events ?

Comment: If the user relaunch the app, u will receive those events.  The operate of updating app will kill the original app process. U can debug this case with install -> open -> uninstall -> install.